# MongoDB : re-shape a document using the properties of an object inside the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection as follows

```json
{
  "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
  "address": {
     "house":"221b",
     "street":"Baker St",
     "city":"London",
  }
},
{
  "name": "James Bond",
  "address": {
     "door_number":"30",
     "address1":"Wellington Square",
     "city":"London",
  }
}
```

I would like to loop through each property in `address` and create a separate fields in main document. That is after executing the command the collection should look like as follows

```json
{
  "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
  "house":"221b",
  "street":"Baker St",
  "city":"London",
},
{
  "name": "James Bond",
  "door_number":"30",
  "address1":"Wellington Square",
  "city":"London",
}
```

The `key` of `address` object is different for different documents.
What is the best way to achieve it using command line ?
I have tried like below

```js
db.employees.find().forEach(function(obj) {
for (var key in obj.address) {
      if (obj.address.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            db.employees.update({ '_id': obj._id }, {
                '$set': { key: obj.address[key] }
            });
      }
    }
});
```

But it adds a field with name `key` only.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: @AlexBlex, is there any way we can update the same document ?

Comment: this is **not** `unwind`, unwind is for arrays/lists, this is reshaping, which you can do with `project`

Comment: @DannyVarod, Thanks, I'll update my questions with that keyword.

Comment: Update and include code - what you have tried to do with project and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: @PrinceFrancis $project works only within context of a single document. Could you rephrase the question, as "same document"is  a bit confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$mergeObjects` to construct your expected output. Then use `$replaceRoot` to wrangle the result.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "merged": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            // fields that you want to keep in outer
            _id: "$_id",
            name: "$name"
          },
          "$address"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$merged"
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GNq-YzzxSW4) for your reference.